# how to get percentage based on counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sample table

```
ID  Name    today_cnt   yesterday_cnt
1   mohan     10020        10080
1   mohan      1200        10080
```

how can I get the percentage values for count difference

1)  10080 - 10020 = 60 = 5 % >> **small difference in record counts**

2)  10080 - 1200  = 8800 = 90 % >> **large difference in record counts**

**output** :

```
ID  Name    today_cnt   yesterday_cnt  Percentage
1   mohan    10020          10080         5%
1   mohan    1200           10080      80%
```

Comment: ID is an identity column.. Right?

Comment: >>10080 - 10020 = 60 = 5 % 

How do you get 5%?

Comment: forgot about identity just concentrate on percentage @ManasaChakka

Comment: @Madhivanan I just gave example what the percentage comes after calculation I will go with that

Comment: what is logic for getting 80% in second row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about your '5%', but smth like this

```
    declare @t table (ID int,  Name varchar(100),   today_cnt int,  yesterday_cnt int);
    insert into @t values
    (1,   'mohan',     10020,       10080),
    (1,   'mohan',      1200,       10080),
    (1,   'mohan',      10090,       10080)


    select *, 
           yesterday_cnt - today_cnt as diff,
           case when yesterday_cnt > today_cnt 
                then cast(round ((yesterday_cnt - today_cnt) *1. / yesterday_cnt * 100, 2) as decimal(3,1)) 
                else 0
           end as [%]
    from @t
```

Comment: this is fine . great

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, Name, today_cnt, yesterday_cnt, 
       ROUND((yesterday_cnt-today_cnt)/yesterday_cnt*100) AS Percentage
FROM TABLE;
```

Something like this ?
I would not advise concatenating the '%' if you want to use the Percentage column as an input, though.

Comment: I have tried this but it will not yield proper results if yesterday count is less than today count then how it need to show 0 not negative values

Answer (score 0):

```
select *, (yesterday_cnt-today_cnt)/100 AS Percentage from tablename
```

Hope this is what you are looking for..

Answer (score 0):

The `select` query will be like this

```
SELECT s.id AS id, Name, 
case when yesterday_count > today_count
then cast(round ((yesterday_count - today_count) / yesterday_count * 100, 2) as decimal(3,0)) else 5 end as 'increment'
FROM users_students AS s
```

Check here in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19891/12)

Comment: I don't want  negative values and proper calculation which suits all scenarios

Comment: Check your 1st calculation,  `10080 - 10020 = 60 = 5 % How do you get 5%? ` how it is possible??

Comment: i just gave you number for reference after applying logic if it gives 2 % or 0.25 % I'm ok with it

Comment: Does it means that all value below 5 will be `5%` ?